# Why are some users stuck routing traffic through CloudFront when DNS no longer points to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have set up a CloudFront distribution that I want to only use periodically.   When I want traffic to go through CloudFront, I change Route53 DNS to have a CNAME that points to the CloudFront distribution. When I want traffic to skip CloudFront, I change DNS to have an A record that points to the origin IP directly.  The TTL on the DNS records is 5 minutes.  Recently, I was able to switch to CloudFront and confirm in logs that traffic started going through it in about 5 minutes.  However, when I attempted to roll back - changing to the A record pointing to the origin, I'm still having users hit CloudFront 4 hours later.  Checking DNS from various machines shows the name can be resolved correctly.  New users hit the origin.  It just appears the CloudFront IP is cached longer than expected for some users.

I understand I can flush dns cache and go to about://net-internals/#dns and clear the browser dns cache, but obviously I can't force users to do that.

Why is browser DNS cache not honoring the records' TTL?
Is there a way to force this to refresh for users?
Is there a better way to switch traffic to go through CloudFront or not?

Comment: There is no way to force that. Its users software that must flush and refresh the dns names it cached.

Comment: "Why is browser DNS cache not honoring the records' TTL?" Resolvers are expected to honor the TTLs, but it is known that some aren't, especially for TTLs considered too low, which is subjective. You are not giving a lot of details on your setup, as other TTLs can come into play also. and using CNAME complicates things. You should try to find out which recursive nameservers your affected users are using. Other than that, not really being about programming, your question is offtopic here. You may get better reply on [su] or [sf] sites but read their help section about what is ontopic or not.